# Error while configuring Reporting Services Integration

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, report-viewer, reporting

I am trying to configure Reporting services with SharePoint via central admin -> General Setting -> Reporting Services Integration

Error is as shown below. What is the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is that you have permissions on to the report server database to access the data. Also please verify the steps u did against the [article which prepared with SP2010 version](http://a2zdinesh.blogspot.in/2012/10/sharepoint-2010-integration-of.html).

Let me know if you still see any issues.

Comment: Ok cool. My report server is installed via default mode and it is not SharePoint mode. are you sure this will not effect the normal working of the report url ? Because many of the users are using the reports via this URL..

Comment: Also there is another problem, when I follow your link, and I go to the report manager, I dont get an choice to select between the SharePoint or native mode. I only can see the native mode.

Comment: Also please advice me whether I should configure the SharePoint reporting service application or whether I should configure the Reporting via Central Admin->General settings->Reporting service integration?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for reason of error. But here are my observations:

Note that for SharePoint 2013 we do not have to configure the Reporting via Central admin -> General application settings -> Reporting service integration. This is specifically for SQL 2008 or 2008 R2. That is the configuration panel for SharePoint Reporting Services 2010. You use it if you want to integrate SharePoint 2013 with an existing SharePoint 2010 SSRS service.

If you have installed the Reporting services 2013 via the SQL server installer, then in SharePoint you need to create a service application instead.

http://rajeshagadi.blogspot.in/2013/07/installing-reporting-services-in.html